# Increment an int using Jbuttons for use with an array

Tags: java, swing, int, jbutton, increment

http://pastebin.com/Dh4jWecK

The program is supposed to, every time a number button is pressed, save that number to an array, however the counter I use to point to the next cell in the array only seems to update when the same button is pressed twice.

For example if input 121323311 into the keypad it prints 1 1 2 1 2 2 3 3 4 for arrayCount.

Edit: My origianal code in my buildGUI() method was:

```
JPanel buttons = new JPanel();
buttons.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,3));

JButton one = new JButton("1");
ButtonEventHandler bl1 = new ButtonEventHandler();
one.addActionListener(bl1);

JButton two = new JButton("2");
ButtonEventHandler bl2 = new ButtonEventHandler();
two.addActionListener(bl2);
```

so on for each button, I've now changed it to:

```
JPanel buttons = new JPanel();
ButtonEventHandler bl = new ButtonEventHandler();
buttons.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,3));

JButton one = new JButton("1");
one.addActionListener(bl);

JButton two = new JButton("2");
two.addActionListener(bl);
```

and it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you have multiple Instances of your `ButtonEventHandler` listening to your individual Buttons. For your purpose, you would need **only one** instance of  `ButtonEventHandler` listening **to all** your Buttons.

Comment: Thank you. I changed my code to only create one ButtonEventHandler and it now works.